# Express $k$ as the sum of three square numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

> How do you express $k$ as the sum of three square numbers, if
>   $$m^2 + 3 = 2k$$
>   where both $m$ and $k$ are integers (both positive or negative if possible).

It is known that $m$ must be an odd integer, positive or negative, so that $k$ is an integer. It is also known that odd integers can be expressed as: $2n + 1$, where $n$ is an integer. Thus, how do you express $k$ as the sum of three square numbers?

Comment: Hint: let $m=2n+1\,$, then $k = 2n^2+2n+2=n^2 + \,?^2\, + \,?^2\,$

Answer (score 2):

Finishing dxiv's hint:
$$k=\frac12(m^2+3)=\frac12((2n+1)^2+3)$$
$$=\frac12(4n^2+4n+4)=2n^2+2n+2$$
$$=n^2+(n^2+2n+1)+1=(n+1)^2+n^2+1^2$$